# $A.createcomponent not working as expected

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, helper

I'm creating a component that, based on a custom fieldset, generates a form.
The point is when is trying to create **lightning:select**, **lightning:duallistbox** and **lightning:textarea** the **$A.createComponent** launches after everything else is created even though the call for the function is made at the right time:

My function **createTextArea** works properly with **lightning:inputRichText** elements but not with textareas:

```
createTextArea: function(component, field, data){
    var result = component.get("v.simpleRecord");  
    //Standard textarea
    if(data.type === "textarea"){
        console.log("entra create textarea");
        $A.createComponent(
            "lightning:textarea",
            data,
            function(newCmp, status, errorMessage){
                if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                    var cmpArray = component.get("v.fieldSetBodyFull");
                    cmpArray.push(newCmp);
                    component.set("v.fieldSetBodyFull", cmpArray);
                    console.log("entra full textarea: " + component.get("v.fieldSetBodyFull"));
                } else if (status === "INCOMPLETE") {
                    console.log("ERROR", "Error creating the component with missing fields.")
                } else if (status === "ERROR") {
                    console.log("ERROR", errorMessage);
                }
            }
        );
    }
    //Textarea HTML Formatted
    if(data.type === "richtext"){
        console.log("entra create richtext");
        $A.createComponent(
            "lightning:inputRichText",
            data,
            function(newCmp, status, errorMessage){
                if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                    var cmpArray = component.get("v.fieldSetBodyFull");
                    cmpArray.push(newCmp);
                    component.set("v.fieldSetBodyFull", cmpArray);
                    console.log("entra full richtext: " + component.get("v.fieldSetBodyFull"));
                } else if (status === "INCOMPLETE") {
                    console.log("ERROR", "Error creating the component with missing fields.")
                } else if (status === "ERROR") {
                    console.log("ERROR", errorMessage);
                }
            }
        );
    } 
},
```

And as you can see with the console, it's getting launched after everything else is made:

[image]

**Does anyone know how to fix this?**

**EDIT:**

How can I implement promises to make it work? Cause it seems that the best solution for me.

Comment: mind includng your components markup? (.cmp)

Comment: AFAIK there are no order guarantees in `$A.createComponent` calls. So if, for example, the `lightning:inputRichText` component was already cached in the browser but the `lightning:textarea` wasn't (so it had to be fetched), the after creation callback of the `lightning:textarea` would very likely come later than you might expect. If you need order guarantees (best to avoided) you would have to code that yourself using e.g. Promises or make a single create call for multiple components that won't complete until all the components have been downloaded and created.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! And how do you implement promises into my code for textarea? Cause I need order guarantees and I've read before about promises but don't know how to put them in my code.. @KeithC

Comment: @molinet Suggest you add that to your question if you think its the way to go.

Comment: Already added. Help would be appreciated! @KeithC